# flutter: when language changes app restarts

Tags: flutter

This code below works perfectly. But when I change the language inside any app screen it takes me out to the login page. I tried to put a function in:

```
   languagesList:  isLoggedIn ?  <String>['en', 'ar'] :  <String>['en', 'ar']
```

But it didn't work. So I want to change language without going back again to the login form.

Any help?

```html
main() async {
  // if your flutter > 1.7.8 :  ensure flutter activated
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn')??false;
   
  ...

  runApp(
    LocalizedApp(
      child: Notification(isLoggedIn:isLoggedIn),
    ),
  );
}


class Notification extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isLoggedIn;
  Notification({this.isLoggedIn});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        
   
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Products_FitnessAndGym()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Cart()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Wishe()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Orders(),
        )
      ],
      
      child: MaterialApp(
        
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: 
           isLoggedIn ? MyHomePage(): LogIn(),
          localizationsDelegates:
              translator.delegates, // Android + iOS Delegates
          locale: translator.locale, // Active locale
          supportedLocales: translator.locals(),
          .........
          ........
```

Comment: try to make a language provider to the whole app and then consume that provider above the material app widget and whenever you need to change the language change it in the change notifier object and notifylisteners. i think it may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
I use official example to simulate this case, you can see working demo below 
`var isLoggedIn` is local variable and `var isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn')??false;` will not be called again  
The quick fix is move `isLoggedIn` out of `main()` and you do not need to pass it to `Notification`

code snippet

```
bool isLoggedIn;
main() async {
  ...

  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') ?? false;

  runApp(LocalizedApp(child: Notification()));
}

class Notification extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: isLoggedIn ? MyHomePage() : LogIn(),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:localize_and_translate/localize_and_translate.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

bool isLoggedIn;
main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await translator.init(
    localeDefault: LocalizationDefaultType.device,
    languagesList: <String>['ar', 'en'],
    assetsDirectory: 'assets/langs/',
    apiKeyGoogle: '<Key>', // NOT YET TESTED
  ); // intialize

  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') ?? false;

  runApp(LocalizedApp(child: Notification()));
}

class Notification extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: isLoggedIn ? MyHomePage() : LogIn(),
      localizationsDelegates: translator.delegates,
      locale: translator.locale,
      supportedLocales: translator.locals(),
    );
  }
}

class LogIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LogInState createState() => _LogInState();
}

class _LogInState extends State<LogIn> {
  void setLogin() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', true);
    isLoggedIn = true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Login Page"),
        // centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Login successful'),
              onPressed: () {
                setLogin();
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("isLoggedIn $isLoggedIn");
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("MyHomePage"),
        // centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            Text(
              translator.translate('textArea'),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
            ),
            OutlineButton(
              onPressed: () {
                translator.setNewLanguage(
                  context,
                  newLanguage: translator.currentLanguage == 'ar' ? 'en' : 'ar',
                  remember: true,
                  restart: true,
                );
              },
              child: Text(translator.translate('buttonTitle')),
            ),
            OutlineButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                print(await translator.translateWithGoogle(
                  key: 'رجل',
                  from: 'ar',
                ));
              },
              child: Text(translator.translate('googleTest')),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```